# Why is $x^2=O(x)$? I can't seem to understand.

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $E$ be a line in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $a$ be an accumulation point of $E$. The functions $t:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called "infinitesimally small" at $a$, if $\lim \limits_{x \rightarrow a} t(x)=0$. 
This is what my teacher wrote.

Now let $f,g:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and let $a$ be an accumulation point of $E$.

$f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x$ tends to $a$, if $f(x)=t(x)g(x)$ where $t$ is infinitesimally small at $a$.

How, for example, does $x^2=O(x)$ follow from those two definitions?

I would appreciate your help...

Comment: $x^{2} = O(x^{2})$ rather than just $O(x)$, as $\not\exists C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^{2} < Cx$, $\forall x > x_{0}$.

Comment: I guess you mean as $x$ tends to $0$?

Comment: Yes... I wrote my attempt, (WHICH IS WHAT ONE SHOULD DO ACCORDING TO THE SITE INSTRUCTIONS) but someone edited it. Therefore it's gone.

Comment: I'm very sorry man, I was editing it before you add you attempt. Please, add it now.

Comment: Ho excuse me, I thought you didn't want me to share it